# Автоподгрузка с прокруткой во Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Делаю своё первое приложение на основе туториала https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/

Использую `Navigation Drawer Activity` и фрагменты, которые загружаются в зависимости от того, что выбрано в меню. Не получается реализовать onScroll() с recyclerview с подгрузкой элементов после достижения конца списка именно во фрагменте (в отдельном activity работает). Класс фрагмента определяется, как:

```
public class FrontPage extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {
```

Может быть есть какие то примеры/туториалы с такой реализацией? (например, подгрузка картинок с инстаграмма или с любым rss) 
Всё что нахожу, загрузка с прокруткой пихается в отдельную активити, а мне важно реализовать это через фрагмент.

Вот код, который реализовывется в классе фрагмента.

```
public class FrontPage extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener{

//Creating a List of items
private List<Item> listItems;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//Volley Request Queue
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 0;


public FrontPage() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_front_page, container, false);
    //Initializing Views
   // final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Initializing our items list
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());

    //Calling method to get data to fetch data
    getData();

    //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this.getActivity());

    //initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listMotivators, this.getActivity());

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    return root;
}

//Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
//This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
//This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(FrontPage.this.getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the item object
        Item item = new Item();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            item.setTitle(json.getString(Config.M_TITLE));
            item.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.M_IMAGE_URL));
            item.setTags(json.getString(Config.M_TAGS_QUOTE));
            item.setComments(json.getString(Config.M_COMMENT_COUNT));
            item.setCreated(json.getString(Config.M_CREATED));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the item object to the list
        listItems.add(item);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Overriden method to detect scrolling
@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        //Calling the method getdata again
        getData();
    }
}
```

}

Фрагмент вызывается стандартно, шаблон для него определён. 
На данном этапе вот на эту строчку студия также ругается:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this.getActivity());
```

говорит, что setOnScrollChangeListener во View can not be applied to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Также не может инициализировать

```
//Initializing ProgressBar
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

UPD Добавляю код адаптера

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

//List to store all items
List<Item> items;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<Item> items, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.items_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    Item Item =  items.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(Item.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.ic_perm_media, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    //Showing data on the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(Item.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(Item.getTitle());
    holder.textViewBody.setText(Item.getBody());
    holder.textViewTags.setText(Item.getTags());
    holder.textViewCreated.setText(Item.getCreated());
    holder.textViewComments.setText(Item.getComments());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewTitle;
    public TextView textViewBody;
    public TextView textViewTags;
    public TextView textViewCreated;
    public TextView textViewComments;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
        textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewBody);
        textViewTags = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTags);
        textViewCreated = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreated);
        textViewComments = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewComments);
    }
}
```

}

UPD2

fragment_front_page.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="me.test.example.FrontPage">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" /></FrameLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="me.test.example.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame">
</FrameLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Сложно представить в чём кардинальное отличие реализации для фрагмента. Покажите код. Расскажите что именно не получается.

Comment: Я руководствовался данным туториалом: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/ 
 Здесь у меня всё работает, но через Activity. Вот как тоже самое реализовать через Fragment?

Например, не получается инициализировать Progressbar.
 final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
где root у меня определён ссылкой на view в oncreateview.. но даже тут если просто я закомментю его, то всё равно не работает. Ошибки нет, но ничего не выводится.

Comment: Вы всё ещё не показали код. Не говорите какая у вас ошибка и есть ли она. Боюсь так мы не сможем вам помочь. Скорее всего вы просто опечатались где-то.

Comment: Вот тут по ссылке https://yadi.sk/d/4AHoHR873GiAFj код класса фрагмента, в котором я пытаюсь это реализовать. Фрагменты вызывать умею. остальной код - адаптера и прочее не менялся и взят с туториала. шаблон xml также стандартно определён. 
В коде например в функции  private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) андроид студио не может инициализировать Progreessbar, выделяет красным findviewbyid, хотя указатель root на view указан там и в других местах этот показатель помогал. Так как я только начинаю, уверен, что со структурой там не всё правильно..

Comment: Мало кто пойдёт по ссылке сторонней. Добавьте код в вопрос. И все детали из комментариев. Читающие вопрос должны видеть инфу в нём, а не продираться через комменты

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас несколько проблем.

1. Вы определили слушатель скрола во фрагменте, не в активити, но передаёте активити как слушатель скрола для `RecyclerView`. При чём передаёте `FragmentActivity`, которая точно не равлизует слушатель скрола, безотносительно того, реализует ли его активити, в которой размещён фрагмент. Вам надо передавать именно фрагмент (т.к. он реализует слушатель), не активити, т.е.

   ```
   recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
   //не активити нужно, а фрагмент
   //recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this.getActivity());
   ```
2. Переменная `root` не доступна за пределами метода `onCreateView`, где вы её объявили. Т.е. вы не можете к ней обращаться в других методах. То же самое с переменной `final ProgressBar progressBar` - её не видно за пределами метода. Вам надо объявить её на уровне класса, там же, где у вас объявлены  `RecyclerView recyclerView` с мэнеджером и адаптером.

Comment: Спасибо, #1 вроде сработал, а вот в #2, когда выношу его в начало класса в виде
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); студия выделяет красным метод findviewbyid.. can not resolve

Также в коде не видит метод setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);  - также can not resolve

Comment: @JetSet, во первых уберите final, он вам тут не нужен. Второе - да, фрагмент не имеет метода  findViewById, инициализируйте прогресс там же и так же как RecyclerView. Третье - не получится проинициализировать вьюху до создания класса. Т.е. инициализировать вью-поле класса сразу при объявлении не получится никак (кроме спец либ). Четвёртое - что за метод `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` - никто кроме вас не знает. Во фрагменте его нет о чём вам компилятор и говорит. Поищите его в активити откуда код переносите. И добавьте во фрагмент.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо, сейчас убегаю, позже отпишусь..

Comment: setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility - это deprecated метод от Activity - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html но  обычно студия указывает deprecated, а тут как будто впервые видит.
Если вью поле проинициализировать без костылей нельзя, то как же тогда реализовать всё это во фрагменте?

Comment: @JetSet, кажется вам просто не нужен setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility - попробуйте просто его убрать. Про инициализацию я же написал... Сделайте также как с RecyclerView. На уровне класса объявляете, а в onCreateView инициализируете. `progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);` - это в onCreateView. А на уровне класса просто объявите. Так же как RecyclerView - `ProgressBar progressBar`

Comment: Удалось запустить, теперь у меня выходит только одна позиция в списке вместо 12. В отладчике смотрел адаптер пошагово - туда приходят все 12 позиций, а показывает всё равно только первую и всё.. даже не знаю куда копать..  Добавил в вопрос код класса адаптера..

Comment: @JetSet покажите разметку активити и фрагмента. Наверное вы ваш RecyclerView в ScrollView поместили или просто высоту по содержимому поставили вместо во весь экран

Comment: добавил код в текст вопроса

Comment: Решил проблему, там у меня был Grid View от другого эксперимента, видимо он всё портил.  Спасибо огромное за помощь, сейчас всё заработало, можно считать вопрос решённым! )

Comment: @JetSet, пожалуйста) Не забудьте отметить ответ верным (галочка слева от тела ответа)